# Apache NiFi Replace Text processor to use control character as delimiter

Tags: apache-nifi

Using replace text processor while converting fixed width file to delimited  with normal character like ';' , '|' ,','  as delimiters is working. However considering \u0001 or [^]A or \^A is not working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

to use special chars you could use `literal` + `unescapeXml` nifi expression functions:

```
${literal('&#1;'):unescapeXml()}
```