# Adding newline when using mergecontent processor to combine each csv flowfile

Tags: csv, merge, newline, apache-nifi

This is the question about MergeContent Processor in Nifi. I would like to add newline when combining each csv flowfile, using MergeContent processor.

Similar to my problem, there was an answer to the question here.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257508/apache-nifi-mergecontent-processor-set-demarcator-as-new-line)

It says I only have to set "Text" for Delimiter Strategy and type "shift+enter" for Dmarcator in property setting.

But it didn't work at all, printing "shift+enter" at the end of each flow file. I also tried "\n","\n" [shift+enter] and other ways and none of them works.

Expected output:

```
column1, column2, column3

value1, value2, value3,
value4, value5, value6,
```

Actual output:

```
column1, column2, column3

value1, value2, value3 shift+enter value4, value5, value6 shift+enter,,,
```

Comment: The same way like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218104/apache-nifi-replace-text-processor-to-use-control-character-as-delimiter/56218650?r=SearchResults#56218650

Comment: I put , ${literal('\n'):unescapeXml()} in Demarcator for property setting. And it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: symbol with code 10 stands for `LF` or `\n`. means you have to use this expression `${literal('&#10;'):unescapeXml()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

symbol with code 10 stands for `LF` or `\n`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

means you have to use following expression: `${literal('&#10;'):unescapeXml()}`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to type in "shift+enter" into the demarcator, you press those keys while in the demarcator value field to create a new line. The value should field should still appear as blank when looking at it, but there will be a new line character if you have pressed those keys.