# read \u0001 delimited file in Groovy

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

In my NiFi job, am invoking a groovy script through InvokeScriptedProcessor. Groovy script supposed to read the \u0001 delimited file and perform some transformation on few columns. Below is the piece of code which i have written to split the columns of a record.

```
def fieldDelimiter = context.getProperty(csvFieldDelimiter).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue()
while (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
  String[] cols = line.split(Pattern.quote(fieldDelimiter),-1)
```

Script is not splitting the record and giving the output same as input. But it is working for other delimiters such as comma, semicolon, pipe etc.,

Below are the settings provided in InvokeScriptedProcessor.

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? If I test the below piece of code in Groovy available in my local desktop, it is working fine.

```
def fieldDelimiter = "\u0001"
def columns = "col1\u0001col2"
String[] cols = columns.split(Pattern.quote(fieldDelimiter),-1)
println "cols output: " + cols[1]
```

EDIT: (flow file content)

[image]

Comment: flowfile contains the "SOH" between the columns. I have added the screenshot in to my question above as EDIT. I don't understand what you are telling. Do you mean to say that there is some issue in my code?

Comment: How do you read the flow file content?

Comment: If I had to bet, it's related to `context.getProperty(csvFieldDelimiter).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue()` - can you debug, if this really holds the `\u0001` _char_ and not the verbatim string `\\u0001` or something else, that get's lost in translation?  Or have you tried with the code you tried in your groovysh (e.g. use a constant `fieldDelimiter` for debugging)?

Comment: @cfrick- Yes, I tried with the below (hardcoded the separator). It is working fine.
`String[] cols = line.split(Pattern.quote('\u0001'),-1)`

Am not sure how to fix the issue when I get the separator from NiFi processor as input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218104/apache-nifi-replace-text-processor-to-use-control-character-as-delimiter/56218650#56218650